# How can I concate month and Day from query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database name test in that there are 3 columns,
`ID (int)`, `created_at(date)`, `temp_date(varchar)`.

I want to execute update's query, which will work as a take Month and Day of `created_at` column's value and update in `temp_at`.

If record in `created_at` is like `'2019-09-04'` then in `temp_date` value will be like `'09-04'`.

How can I execute the query will you help??

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html and try something

Comment: I tried this query `select cast(YEAR(created_at) as varchar(4)) + '-' + DATENAME(mm, created_at) FROM test;`

but this is not working

Comment: It would be rather helpful to know what you wanted the `temp_date` string to look like!

Comment: If record in created_at is like `2019-09-04` then in temp_date value will be like `09-04`

Comment: And if it is based upon the contents of `created_at` then WHY bother storing it in the database at all. Generate it as part of an query that actually wants to use it instead

Comment: It is my task, will you please help me to build a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would update each rows `temp_date` column based on the `created_at` date

```
UPDATE table 
SET temp_date = CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(created_at),2,'0'), '-', LPAD(DAY(created_at),2,'0'))
```

However rather than storing a column that is purely based upon the contents of another column, you could just create this column in an query you wanted to use this column in like this

```
SELECT  created_at, 
        CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(created_at),2,'0'), '-', LPAD(DAY(created_at),2,'0')) as temp_date
FROM table
```

Or as Paul suggested using `DATE_FORMAT()` a much simpler idea would be

```
UPDATE table 
SET temp_date = DATE_FORMAT(the_time, '%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thankq So much I also come up with this solution `UPDATE test set temp_date = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m"), '-', DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d"))

`

Comment: Just use `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%d")`. There is no need for `CONCAT()`. But I agree, that it's a bad idea to store redundant data.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are probably right, I got all caught up in all that text manipulation and refused to put it down. :)

Comment: Another way would be to use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Ooo I like that idea @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
UPDATE test t2 
 inner join (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y %M') as datestr, id 
             FROM test) t1 
 ON t2.id = t1.id
 SET temp_date  = t1. datestr;
```

This writes 2019 July into your temp_date.
Now you can change DATE_FORMAT to your needs.